# How to start Visual Studio Code within Anaconda Env

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am running into trouble running a python program inside visual studio code on my Windows 10 PC.

When I start a python session from the terminal and say `import cv2` I get no errors:

[image]

When I go through the command prompt and start `VSCode` from within the env, I get the `ModuleNotFoundError`

[image]

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

When I try to run the program as `python gui.py` from within the environment my command prompt crashes with the error message:

[image]

I'm not sure how to ask this question other than wondering is there a way to start my IDE from within the python env so that it can locate all the local packages.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that cv2 is installed in that environment?  Is it in `pip freeze`?

Comment: I can't really tell what command prompt you're executing from.  Either way, my process is typically 1) `./project/scripts/activate.ps1` (or `activate.bat` depending on your flavor) then 2) `code .`  Code is typically added to your $PATH$ environment variable, so you do not need to cd all the way into that directory.

Comment: @Jaberwocky "code" as in VS Code correct?

Comment: Yes.  If you type code in at command prompt.  VS Code will start, assuming you chose the default installation selections.

Comment: Also keep in mind, I said `code .` which would be executed from within the project folder.  You can type `code` without the `.` from anywhere.  The `.` just tells VS Code to open that directory.  As an example. you can type `code /path/to/project` or `code ~/foo/bar.txt`

Comment: Also, if you're starting your virtual environment from within Anaconda (command prompt terminal), you do not need to run `activate.ps1` or `activate.bat`.  Just `cd` into the project directory, and type `code .`.

Answer (score 21):

1. Make sure you have **visual studio code** installed in your system.
2. Make sure your **environment variables** are configured. (see below image for reference)
   [image]
3. Go to your **Anaconda command prompt**, and type **`code --version`** (see below image for reference)
   [image]
4. To Launch VS code from Anaconda/Window command prompt type **`code`**. (see below image)

[image]

Comment: So the short answer is
`code`, Thanks Manjeet.

Answer (score 1):

1. open anaconda prompot
2. activate your enviroment //activate your_env
3. write "code" then Enter